# angularJS Dynamic scope Definition for an isolated scope custom Directive Definition

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an isolated scope custom directive say

```
<my_isolate_scope_dir  columns="columns" />
```

And the directive Definition goes something like this.

```
 .directive("myIsolateScopeDir", ["$compile","$templateCache",function($compile,$templateCache){
    return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        columns: '=',
            },
    templateUrl: 'customdirective.html',

    }
    }]);
```

The question is ,in the directive definition `scope:{}` can i define one more scope variable dynamically whose value is coming from the parent scope variable `columns`.

The parent controller  can be

```
$scope.columns=[{"name":"x","isLink":true,"onClickFunction":"clickedx"},{"name":"y","isLink":true,"onClickFunction":"clickedy"}]
$scope.clickedx=fucntion()
{
 console.log("x is clicked");
}
```

i want my custom directive `scope` definition to be

```
    scope: {
        columns: '=',
        clickedx: '&', //this is added dynamically to the definition based on the value in columns array
        clickedy: '&' //this is added dynamically to the definition based on the value in columns array
            },
```

let me know if this can be achieved in the same way or is there any other simpler way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually inject the methods into the scope using `$parse`.

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    if (scope.columns) {
        scope.columns.forEach(function (column) {
            if (column.onClickFunction) {
                // column.onClickFunction is a string(eg, clickedx), we need to treat this as a function in scope
                var fn = column.onClickFunction + "()";

                // get a reference to the function defined in the scope
                var getParentMethod = $parse(fn);

                // Use of Locals: apart from accessing the properties of the scope, you will be able to pass few properties using locals, which will have the precedence over the properties of scope

                // For example if the markup is -- <button on-click="test(arg1, arg2)"
                // arg1, arg2 needs to be evaluated in the scope
                // As isolateScope breaks the inheritance chain, we need to pass element.scope() to the parser function to access the arg1, arg2 properties from controllers scope

                // define a method in the scope with the value of column.onClickFunction (eg, clickedx)
                scope[column.onClickFunction] = function (locals) {

                    // when scope.clicedx is executed execute the method defined in the controller. 
                    return getParentMethod(element.scope(), locals);
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what are we doing in the last three lines

Comment: This way whenever the clickedx() is invoked `locals.scope = element.scope(); ` is executing twice.the first time with the actuals arguments sent to the function ,second with undefined arguments which is leading to an error.the function is calling itself.

Comment: locals.scope assignment is not required. I have removed that.

Comment: Can you create a plnkr/fiddle if you are still facing the issue?

Comment: the function is calling itself and ended up in `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73069/discussion-between-divya-mv-and-vinay-k).